# Redirect woocommerce customers to different pages based on which page they are logging in

Tags: authentication, redirect, woocommerce, registration

I am using a short code for woocommerce login form to show the login form on different pages which is keeping users on the same page after login. This is ok for a few pages but in most cases, I want to redirect users to a different page, the redirect location will be determined based on the page they are logging in to.

```
add_shortcode( 'wc_login_form_custom', 'custom_separate_login_form' );

function custom_separate_login_form() {
    if (is_admin()) 
        return;

    if (is_user_logged_in()) 
        return; 

    ob_start();

    woocommerce_login_form();
    
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `woocommerce_login_redirect` filter for this.

For example:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_login_redirect', 'custom_wc_login_redirect_rules', 10, 2 );
function custom_wc_login_redirect_rules( $url, $user ) {
    
    // Do whatever conditions with $url you want
    // E.g. redirect to My Account page if user logs in from 'my-custom-page' URL slug
    if( str_contains( $url, 'my-custom-page' ) ) {
        $url = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
    }

    return $url;
}
```

Comment: I have added this filter to the functions.php of my child theme it does not seems to redirect me to the correct page. It is just showing completely white screen on the same page.

Comment: Hi @KokabHasnain , I just tried it and it works perfectly fine on my side. Do you see any error messages in PHP error log and/or in JS console?